# corresponding $.ajax() call for a curl command

Tags: jquery, json, curl, http-post

I want to know how to write corresponding jquery ajax call for following curl command :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}' http://localhost:8080/authentication/signIn
```

So far, what I have tried is as follows :

```
            login_url = 'http://localhost:8080/authentication/signIn';
            post_data = {username : 'admin', password : 'admin'};

            $.ajax({
            url: login_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: post_data,
            success: function (data) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(){
              alert("Cannot get data");
            }
        });
```

But then I get the error at server side : Request object has no attribute json (which I am trying to access as cherrypy.request.json in signIn function). But the same works for given curl command. What I am missing on in the ajax call?

Comment: hi Rakhi, thanks for your reply. But I am still getting the same error at the server : Request object has no attribute json.

Comment: Your ajax call appears to be fine. Did you check if there are any js errors shown in the console?

Comment: actually the request is reaching to the server but I am getting an error at the server that "Request object has no attribute json". But again this works well for given CURL command. So I am not sure what am I missing in the ajax call.

Comment: Try removing the dataType from your json call?